# Solution to combine many small vectors into one large image?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Lets say i have ten separate vector files, each of which is 100 pixels square.

I would like to combine them into one large single image, ten smaller files across, ten smaller files down (so a grid of 10x10) resulting in a final image 1k by 1k pixels.

Are there any tools to do this or existing methods? Recording an action to do it is giving me headache at the moment...!

All advice appreciated

Comment: That's... not how vectors work. The whole point of a vector is that it can be _any_ size, and you can then export the resulting image to a raster (which _is_ pixelated) of any resolution you damn well please.

Answer (score 1):

Vector images don't have pixels.

You can use almost any vector image editor to import vector files, lay them out in a grid, and export as raster or vector images.

You can copy and paste images directly from one document into another. You can Place files directly into another document. Illustrator even supports dragging and dropping vector files right into the document.  Illustrator has grids, snap to grid, smart guides and alignment tools already built in.

I don't know why you think you would need to record an Action in Illustrator to do this. It's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If I have 100 objects I want to arrange in a 10 x 10 grid:

Set guides or draw square the size of your final file and "split into grid" with 10 rows, 10 columns, no bleeds.

Lock your guide in the bottom layer.

Take the first ten objects, if they have an order then put the first one in the first square of the top row of your guide, the last of the 10 in the last square of the top row of your guide.

Make sure your align dialogue window is set to "align to object"

Select all first 10 objects and use align "Vertical Align Center" to put them on the same horizontal line then use "Horizontal Distribute Center" to space all ten evenly across the row.

For the second 10 items place the first one (#11) under #1 and the last one (#20) under #10. Select items 10-20 and perform the distribute and align.
Do this for all remaining objects/rows.

Now use the alignment tools to neaten up your grid.

Select all first column items and "Horizontal Align Center", then all your last column items align center, then select each row or column and use the align tools to get everything in place.